# Why maven module got the dependencies from the parent automatically?

Tags: dependencies, maven-3

I've created a parent project and three maven module projects. When I added dependencies in the parent project, the dependencies were added to all module projects automatically. This is not what I want. I want to parent POM holds all dependencies defined and add the actual dependencies the module project as needed by providing groupId and artifactId.
How can I stop m2eclipse automatically including the dependencies from parent project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between `build.dependencies` and `build.dependencyManagement.dependencies`.

Dependencies define actual dependencies, whereas dependency management only defines dependency versions that are (to be) used for dependencies.

Either of those are inherited, but that's fine. It allows to perform dependency management from within the parent while the dependencies (that are being managed) are defined in the child projects.

Note that there is a trend to steer away from Maven dependency management through inheritance, and use composition instead ("[importing dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies)").

Comment: Actually, I didn't put DependencyManagerment tag in the parent POM. The problem was gone after add the tag.